# NGRX, filter from selector

Tags: angular, selector, ngrx

I am using below selector:

```
export const selectorPersonData = createSelector(featureSelector, (state, props) => {
    try {
        return state.departmentData.filter(filt => filt.currentPosition.jobId === props.workSelectProps)
            .map(job => job.assignedJob
                .map(item => item.dealId));
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

In returning I got `[[idA,idB]]`

I tried a lot of solution with flatMap etc... but I did not get:

```
[idA, idB]
```

And I would like to get that data from selector.

And there are a double map. Nested Maps.

```
 Map<namePersons, Map<workData, InformationModel>>>
```

Comment: Please add code for your interfaces. How does the state looks like? How does the departmentData looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have nested `map` calls you will get nested arrays. You will need to flatten the returned arrays to get the desired results.

Try:

```
return [].concat.apply([], state.departmentData.filter(filt => filt.currentPosition.jobId === props.workSelectProps)
        .map(job => job.assignedJob
            .map(item => item.dealId)));
```

HTH

Comment: I tried similar solution. But I got:
```[empty, 'idA, idB', 'idA, idB']```

Comment: @profiler can you include what you tried? also, some sample data would be very helpful. With the small sample you provided, this works fine; see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k4xLmsbz/

Comment: I am sorry, my fault! It is working perfectly. I used ```*ngFor"person of persons"``` but on template I send ```persons``` instead of ```person```. Thank you so much for Your help!